# transfer form data between portlets in different pages

Tags: liferay, portlet

I want to show data from one portlet to another portlet in liferay
but the portlet is not JSF.
Specifically I want to show form data from one portlet to other portlet not in the same page What do you offer to do.

Answer (score 3):

Use inter portlet communication to share the data between different portlets. This can be done as following: `actionRequest.getPortletSession().setAttribute("dataToBeShared",
                dataValue, PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);`

Later you can retrieve the same by giving `actionRequest.getPortletSession().getAttribute("dataToBeShared",PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);`

Hope it helps !!!